# In Perl on Hadoop, how to get file of file being processed by mapper?

Tags: perl, hadoop

In Hadoop, I am passing in a directory/* with various files. The names of the files are important for the processing of the data. I need this solution in Perl.

I believe the Java equivalent is job.get("map.input.file"). I looked for about 45 minutes and I can't find the Perl solution.

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the job configuration variables are serialized to the process environment, with the property names made 'safe' using some code in the `StreamUtils.safeEnvVarName` method.

Basically this method will replace any non [0-9A-Za-z] character in the property name with an underscore, so `map.input.file` should be available as an environment variable named `map_input_file`

Answer (score 0):

To summarize with code what Chris nicely explained, you need the following two lines to get an input filename and print it to stderr:

```
my $filename = $ENV{"map_input_file"};
print STDERR "Input filename is: $filename\n";
```